# How to compare 2 field in TDS using TQL query

Tags: talend

Good day,

Normally, in TDS, I will key in my TQL query to filter the result I want, for example,

```
"creationDate >= " + 1689091200000 + " and creationDate < " + 1689177600000
```

And I will get the correct JSON response.

Now I want to do compare on this 2 field to check whether they having same value or not, so I put in TQL as follow:

```
"lastUpdateDate != creationDate"
```

[image]
However, I am hitting the following error:

```
{
  "code": "TDS_ALL_TQL_SYNTAX_ERROR",
  "message": "TQL_SYNTAX_ERROR",
  "cause": "Error: !=",
  "context": {
    "campaignId": "645f5e08dbeeba28d19e66dc",
    "property": ""
  }
}
```

[image]
I spend a lot of time to google on this, but still cant get any answer.

Anyone can advise?

Comment: are the date format consistent? have you also tried '<>'

Comment: @Allanckw, yes they are consistent.Yes, I tried the `<>` also, will get `"Unexpected expression: lastUpdateDate<>creationDate"`

Comment: u might need to show us ur full query, it's hard to tell what's going on without it.. the syntax looks correct on its own

Comment: @Allanckw, that is the full query, let me put the screen shot.

Comment: According to the reference, `!=` is indeed valid. https://help.talend.com/r/en-US/Cloud/data-stewardship-user-guide/tql-with-tds-components-api I suggest you experiment further to isolate. Do any of these work without error? `lastUpdateDate != 1689091200000` or even `1 != 1`

Comment: Try removing the quotation marks

Comment: @Allanckw, tried, is the same.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid `lastUpdateDate != 1689091200000` is good to go without error. But `1689091200000 != lastUpdateDate` will hit error. i believe I cant put variable on the second place.

Comment: try !~ not matches

Comment: @Allanckw, do u means change to `lastUpdateDate !~ creationDate` ?

Comment: yes, correct...

Comment: alternative, why not use 
`TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND , lastUpdateDate , creationDate ) == 0` ?